# where is 'bootstrap'? can't install CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, bootstrap-modal, cmake-gui

I want to install CMake on my server with linux OS.
But I can't find any 'bootstrap' file, so can't install it for 3 hours.
I want to go next step,,
please help me. what's wrong with these step? (see below)

1. I downloaded 'cmake-3.28.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz' <- My status: Ubuntu 20.04
2. I upzipped it
3. As far as I know, the next step is:

```
cd ./cmake-3.28.1/
./configure --qt-gui
./bootstrap && make -j8 && make install -j8
#./bootstrap --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
```

in the above line, I went to next step by substituting `./configure~` with `_configure~`
but when I went to the next line, I got error like this:

> zsh: no such file or directory: ./bootstrap

I know that there is no bootstrap folder or file in my `cmake-3.28.1` directory.
I looked around many posts about installing CMake, so I found that I couldn't go next step unless I resolve that 'Bootstrap' line.

Has anyone experienced same situations??

Comment: You downloaded a binary distribution, not the source code. There is nothing to build.

Comment: Doesn't your "linux os" come with a software package system that automatically downloads abd installs packages, like apt, yum, pacman, and it already has cmake package available?

Comment: @tkausl you mean I tried to 'source' download, but the file that I downloaded to my server was 'binary' code, right?

Comment: I don't know what you _tried_ to download. The filename `cmake-3.28.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` however tells me that this is a binary distribution and you're trying to compile from source.

Comment: @KamilCuk I already have the package system like apt, and my server already has cmake with older version. 
But even when I try to update or remove that cmake, it says that cmake cannot be found; so I am trying to install the latest version of cmake.
In this case, do I need to find and delete all older version cmake cash files?

Comment: Hi, I do not follow. `when I try to update or remove that cmake` Why would you remove? Just install. `it says that cmake cannot be found` That sounds like a problem. Please give (a lot) more information.  What is "it"? What shell are you using? What linux distribution are you using? What linux version? What is the content of /etc/os-release? What cmake version did you install? Which "apt" command exactly have you executed? apt or apt-get? What is the output when you try to install cmake with apt? Is the "that cmake cannot be found" the only reason you are installing newer version?

Comment: Finally, why install newer version from source, and not from apt? Cmake has apt repositories that they publish with fresh stuff, once again, no reason to use build it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line ` In this case, do I need to find and delete all older version cmake cash files?` "Cash" files sounds like a typo. It is hard to answer what you "need to". I am guessing, that you don't "need to" bootstrap cmake in the first place, and that is a XY question. You are just interested how to install cmake on your system.

Comment: Check "status = option -s" : `dpkg -s cmake` . May be your current cmake also was a manual build / a non Ubuntu binary package ??